# How to use different language for date_trunc by month in Django using Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, to-char

How do I print month names using different language?

```
to_char(date_trunc( 'month', date) , 'MON-YYYY') AS date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TM` prefix with `Month` as `to_char` function's second argument

```
select to_char(date_trunc( 'month', date) , 'TMMonth') AS date
```

to show your month name depending on the parameter returning from

```
# show lc_time;
```

command.

By the way,

> *you can change your session's current `lc_time` parameter by using*
>
> *`set lc_time = 'fr_FR';` and get `Avril` from the query in French, or*
>
> *`set lc_time = 'tr_TR';` and get `Nisan` from the query in Turkish as examples.*

<kbd>[Run This Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u38arWh5k7rH7qUTNFB7Tq/0)</kbd>